# PIC 18f4550 I2C Error ccs , the microcontroller gets stuck when i2c starts

Tags: c, pic, microchip

Im trying to link some pic 18f4550 via I2C using CCS and proteus. 
I have a working I2C proyect witch runs perfect on pic 16f876, but the chip gets stuck with the 18f4550, concretly on the line:

i2c_start();

im very curious with the reason.

I attach 2 links with both versions.

Here is a simplyfied version of the master chip:

```
#include  18f4550.h 


#FUSES XT,NOPROTECT 

#use delay(clock=20M)

#use i2c(Master,fast,sda=PIN_A0,scl=PIN_A1, force_sw)



void Envio_I2C(direccion, posicion, dato){

   i2c_start();            // Comienzo comunicación
   i2c_write(direccion);   // Dirección del esclavo en el bus I2C
   i2c_write(posicion);    // Posición donde se guardara el dato transmitido
   i2c_write(dato);        // Dato a transmitir
   i2c_stop();             // Fin comunicación
   delay_ms(50);
 }



void main()
{


 Envio_I2C(0xA0, 0x01, 0xAA);


 }
```

I dont understand why its not working because it runs well on the 16 line
Here the links of the working proyect(16f)  and the not working one (18f), thanks a lot x ur attention guys!

[Working 16f proyect proteus + ccs](http://www.forosdeelectronica.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=144345&d=1464653488)
[Not working 18f proyect](http://www.forosdeelectronica.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=144346&d=1464653516)

Comment: Any reason why you haven't declared the function properly? Your code needlessly bloats the stack. Bad thing to do on such an ancient microcontroller.

Comment: @Lundin To be clear, you're referring to the fact main should be either "void main(void)" or "int main(void)?"

Comment: @RyanB Not at all, this is a freestanding system so void main is just fine and de facto standard. I was referring to `void Envio_I2C(direccion, posicion, dato)`. Won't compile on a decent compiler, but I guess this is some crap compiler like MPLAB.